# Why does Swing in my Java Applet flicker on fast mouse over?

Tags: java, swing, applet

I made a Java Applet with some Standard GUI Components on it. I used the [MigLayout](http://www.miglayout.com/) Manager.

If I move the mouse slowly over the various GUI Components everything appears to be fine, but if I move the mouse fast, it flickers.

What could make that nasty ugly redraw?
(Core 2 Duo 6300, 2GB Ram, Windows XP)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One thought would be to check your code (and/or the MigLayout code) for unnecessary `repaint()` operations.

Custom UIs and layouts can cause weird problems sometimes...

Comment: You're right. Thanks. I found out, that I used a custom component which registered a MouseListener.

Answer (score 0):

you could use double buffering in java applet to improve screen refreshing speed. ask more if details needed..

Comment: According to http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/
double buffering is ENABLED BY DEFAULT for all Swing components.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bugger:
I used a custom [ClosableTabbedPaint](http://www.koders.com/java/fidA4A2ADA8513A83E2024E550ADF906CAE16A4EDFB.aspx?s=cdef%3Aaccount) Class.