# What is the best "closable TabbedPane" Component in Java?

Tags: java, swing, tabs, components

After solving my [flicker issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/147802/why-does-swing-in-my-java-applet-flicker-on-fast-mouse-over), I wonder if there is a better closable Tabbed Pane, then the one that pops up on top by googling for [closabletappedpane](http://www.google.ch/search?q=closeabletabbedpane)?
(you recognize it by its [processMouseEvents Method](http://www.koders.com/java/fidA4A2ADA8513A83E2024E550ADF906CAE16A4EDFB.aspx?s=cdef%3Aaccount#L125))

I especially need one, that never flickers :-)

Please post your experience, links with your own closable Tabbed Panes here.

Answer (score 4):

There is a [sample implementation of closable tabs](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/examples/components/index.html#TabComponentsDemo) using [JTabbedPane](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/tabbedpane.html) in the JDK.

Comment: sadly I'm forced to use JDK 1.5... and there is no JTabbedPane#setComponentAt(...)
But thank you anyway.

Answer (score 3):

[JideTabbedPane](http://www.jidesoft.com/products/oss.htm) is pretty awesome and it's in the common layer (which is open source). It supports all sorts of sweet features to make Java apps not seem so crusty. We've had great success with it on my project.

Comment: Jide looks nice, but the binaries use 1MB and I just want to use the closable tabbed panes. But thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

I really recommend to follow tutorial mentioned above. It is simple to create such a tab and you have *full* control over its behavior.